# C# Parse HTML String WITHOUT using HTMLAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, html-parsing

I have an Html String which I need to parse, but **WITHOUT** using `HTMLAgilityPack`.

Using `XPath` is quite simple, but how do I get it working using `XPath`?

Comment: or using WebBrowser control...

Comment: No, you cannot use `XPath` directly because Html is NOT Xml. Html allows tag without closing but Xml do not.

Comment: Also, what do you want to get from parsing html? If you just want to extract some variable, using regular expression and treating the html like string will work.

Comment: For WinForms there is `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` which acts like a simple web browser (http://stackoverflow.com/a/56629). On ASP .NET, you need Regex class and creating HTML parser manually, since XPath usage usually combined with `HtmlAgilityPack`.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't want to use HtmlAgilityPack? What you're asking is akin to saying, "I want to drive a nail, *without* using a hammer." Use the best available tool for the job.

Comment: @JimMischel The parsing routine is called from unmanaged code, hence the `HTMLAgilityPack` crashes when it tries to create the class `HtmlWeb` or when it tries to create a `HtmlDocument` from a simple `String`. That is why I can't use `HTMLAgilityPack`.

Comment: Perhaps the problem isn't with HtmlAgilityPack, but rather with the way your code is handling the call from unmanaged code. I don't have any experience calling HtmlAgilityPack from a method that's called from unmanaged code, but I've done plenty of other things from such a method. It should "just work." I'd suspect an error in the way you're doing the callback, but without an example and some specifics about the error you encounter, I can't say what it is. In short, I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your objection to HTML Agility Pack. I've just written a lightweight HTML parse and posted it on Github as [HTML Monkey](https://github.com/SoftCircuits/HtmlMonkey).

The initial version does not support XPath, but I'm still working on the project and looking for feedback and suggestions.